# parsley.js - custom validation for date field

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, parsley.js

I have been reading the [parsley.js docs](http://parsleyjs.org/) and I have tried to write a custom validator to validate if a date is greater than todays date.

I have the conditional code written, but I am completly confused about how to apply the conditional error message.

I have completed the task with a parsley maxlength validator, but realise that this is less than perfect.

**How do I write the custom validation with parsley?**

Here is my js/jq code that dynamically adds & deletes the validation using the maxlength:

```
if(formattedStartDate > todaysDate) {

    $('#id_voluntary_start_date').attr('data-parsley-maxlength', '1');
    $('#id_voluntary_start_date').attr('data-parsley-maxlength-message', '{% trans "Commencement Date must not be greater than today." %}');
    $('#id_voluntary_start_date').parsley();
} else {
    $('#id_voluntary_start_date').attr('data-parsley-maxlength', '50');
}
```

Any help with implementing the custom validation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all set one hidden textbox and store today's date in it and just write below code on date field you want to check.

```
data-parsley-dlte = "#hiddentextboxid",
data-parsley-dlte_message = "Your custom message"
```

Don't forget to set parsley on the form in which you have your dom elements.

If this doesn't work check the version of [parsley js](http://parsleyjs.org/).

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is register your custom validator either globally (in window.ParsleyConfig) or for your particular form as follows:

```
  myForm.parsley({
    validators: {
        custom: function (value) {
            var now = new Date();
            var date = new Date(value);
            return date < now;
        }
    },
    messages: {
        custom: 'Commencement Date must not be greater than today'
    }
});
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0agdqqgL/2/) with a sample

Comment: Thanks for the code & the jsFiddle. This has helped me a lot. I am almost there. How do I specify the validation to only a specific text input id? For example: <input type="text" id="id_commencement_date" name="commencement_date" />

Comment: It can be accomplished by using "inputs" option where you need to provide the selector, such as "inputs: '#date1'" (see jsFiddle)